# Camera devices suddenly disappeared on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 14.04, webcam, camera, linux-headers

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on Asus Tuf. I have a very weird problem with the camera devices. When I restart the computer, both the integrated webcam and the external webcam are working perfectly and I can do meetings on zoom, google meet,... Then suddenly, both devices are disappeared and any meeting tool can detect them. I try with cheese and other tools but they can't detect anything.
Note that /dev/video0... exists at the beginning, then it disappears. I feel so confused because I need to restart the computer every time I lost the devices. Does any help please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing a hard reset.

1. Long press the power button (say 10+ secs) until your system is off.
2. Repeat step one until you see your computer come on (continue to hold power button) and goes back off.
3. Then turn on your computer normally.

See if problem persists.

If that does not fix it, alternatively, check if there's a problem with the Camera drivers and repair accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but It is the same behavior. It works but after some mins/hours, I have to restart the computer!!

Comment: @BetterEnglish check out this thread for some of the fixes in this: [link](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-signed/+bug/1881757)

Comment: nothing is resolved!